# Importing .obj-file in QGIS 3.10.5

Tags: 3d, photogrammetry, qgis-3

I wonder if it is possible to simply import `.obj` and `.jpg` (texture) files in QGIS and implement them in an existing map.

I found this answer [QGIS, point clouds and photogrammetry](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62020/qgis-point-clouds-and-photogrammetry/271124#271124) but it isn´t exactly what I am looking for.

So my question is if there is an simple way to work in QGIS with `.obj`-files?